# Solve the mgf and expected value of a discrete random variable

Tags: statistics, expectation, moment-generating-functions

This problem is from Casella and Berger

A distribution cannot be uniquely determined by a finite collection of moments, as this example from Romano and Siegel (1986) shows. Let X have the normal distribution, that is, X has pdf

$f_x(X)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-x^2/2}$, $-\infty<x<\infty$

Define a discrete random variable Y by

$P(Y=\sqrt{3})=P(Y=-\sqrt{3})=\frac{1}{6}$, $P(Y=0)=\frac{2}{3}$.

Show that

$EX^r=EY^r$ for $r=1, 2, 3, 4, 5$

---

I have solved that $EX^r$ are 0, 1, 0 , 3, 0 as $r=1, 2, 3, 4, 5$.
How to make the mgf of Y and get the expection?

Comment: You don't need mfg of $Y$ to compute its moments. The distribution is so simple, it's easier to compute it directly from definition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The MGF of $Y$ is by definition

\begin{align}
\text{M}_Y(s) &= E[e^{sY}]\\
              &= \sum_y e^{sy}p_Y(y)
\end{align}

where $p_Y(y)$ is the PMF of $Y$. You can expand that sum as

$$M_Y(s) = \frac{1}{6}e^{s\sqrt3} + \frac{1}{6}e^{-s\sqrt3} + \frac{2}{3}$$

As usual, the $n$-th moment would be given by

$$E[Y^n] = \frac{d^n}{ds^n}M_Y(s)\bigg|_{s=0}$$